# How i can navigate desktop app to default mail provider set in my system while on click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

I try these code but it generate error dialog box with "An unexpected error occurred and the application will reload" and application reload successfully

```
$email.click(crm_core.callback_function(function () {
 var emailaddress = contact.email();
 if (emailaddress == '')
 return;
 emailaddress = emailaddress.trim();
 var newurl = 'mailto:' + contact.prompt() + " <" + emailaddress + ">";
 window.location = newurl;
}));
```

**My Question is how to open default mail provider in my system to compose mail from my app**

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode your url. Example space => `%20`, `<` => `%3C`, `>` => `%3E`

Comment: Thanks Joey Chong,its not working on windows 8.1 tablet. If you have any other solution please suggest me.